# angular with html for get value from db using $http.get in angular

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs

I need to pass my php value(id) to via angular another php (select.php)
this is my angular code:

```
$http.get("select.php",{'id':stu_id}).success(function(data)
{
$scope.pagesdata=data;
})
```

please tell me this is correct code or not...

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `params` object.

```
$http.get("select.php", {
   params: {'id':stu_id} 
}).success(function(data) {
   $scope.pagesdata=data;
});
```

OR query params

```
$http.get("select.php?id="+stu_id)
.success(function(data) {
   $scope.pagesdata=data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are send the data as json.The Json only suitable for post method.Try to change the send method as post or change the url formate like below..!!

```
$http.get("select.php/"+stu_id).success(function(data)
{ 
   $scope.pagesdata=data;
});
```